# Texture paint settings 2.8

Tags: texture-painting

I was wondering if someone could tell me where the texture painting settings -the ones that were in the tool bar were moved to?
I'm trying to start texture painting, I don't know where to go to find paint slot settings and such.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I understand what you are looking for.

What I figured out is, there are not many preinstalled settings but you can create numerous own.

[image]

- Open the brush setting with the tools button (2)
- Create a new (default) brush withe current settigns (1)
- Select out of all created brushes (3)

When converting a 2.79 blender file to 2.80, existing brush settings (at least some) are taken over.

Comment: This was not what I was looking for, but it is good to know!  I found what I needed:  I was looking for how to add a paint slot to my object so I could start painting.  It is the panel that you press 'n' to pull up.